# How to call the validateRecruiters function with different parameters

Tags: javascript, typescript, design-patterns

How to call the validateRecruiters function in the following code depending on the interview type (TECHNICAL_INTERVIEW or HR_INTERVIEW). Notice that the validateRecruiters function takes more parameters in the HR_INTERVIEW call. Could you suggest which design pattern to use so that will be universal in every case?

```
import { getHrRecruiters, getRecruiters } from '../queue';
import { validateTechnicalInterview } from './validateTechnicalInterview';
import { matchHrRecruiters } from './matchHrRecruiters';
import { THrInterviewer, THrRecruit, TRecruit } from '../../types';

export const recruitersCategoryHandlers = {
  TECHNICAL_INTERVIEW: {
    getter: getRecruiters,
    setter: {
      validateRecruiters: (
        recruiters: THrInterviewer[],
        recruit: TRecruit | THrRecruit
      ) => validateTechnicalInterview(recruiters, recruit),
    },
  },
  HR_INTERVIEW: {
    getter: getHrRecruiters,
    setter: {
      validateRecruiters: (
        recruiters: THrInterviewer[],
        recruit: TRecruit | THrRecruit,
        param3: any,
        param4: any
      ) => matchHrRecruiters(recruiters, recruit as THrRecruit, param3, param4),
    },
  },
};
```

```
const matchedSlots = getMatchingSlots(
          recruitersCategoryHandlers[
            interviewCategory as EInterviewCategory
          ].setter.validateRecruiters(???),
          slotsWithEmail
        );
```

The solution works when I have the same parameters. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to do this with different parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Rerecruiters *CategoryHandlers* object is used as a lookup table to determine the appropriate handler functions based on the interview type.

```
import { getHrRecruiters, getRecruiters } from '../queue';
import { validateTechnicalInterview } from './validateTechnicalInterview';
import { matchHrRecruiters } from './matchHrRecruiters';
import { THrInterviewer, THrRecruit, TRecruit } from '../../types';

// Define strategy interfaces
interface ValidateRecruitersStrategy {
  validateRecruiters(recruiters: THrInterviewer[], recruit: TRecruit | THrRecruit, ...params: any[]): any;
}

// Implement strategy for technical interview
class TechnicalInterviewStrategy implements ValidateRecruitersStrategy {
  validateRecruiters(recruiters: THrInterviewer[], recruit: TRecruit | THrRecruit): any {
    return validateTechnicalInterview(recruiters, recruit);
  }
}

// Implement strategy for HR interview
class HrInterviewStrategy implements ValidateRecruitersStrategy {
  validateRecruiters(recruiters: THrInterviewer[], recruit: TRecruit | THrRecruit, ...params: any[]): any {
    return matchHrRecruiters(recruiters, recruit as THrRecruit, ...params);
  }
}

// Define recruitersCategoryHandlers using strategy pattern
export const recruitersCategoryHandlers = {
  TECHNICAL_INTERVIEW: {
    getter: getRecruiters,
    setter: new TechnicalInterviewStrategy(),
  },
  HR_INTERVIEW: {
    getter: getHrRecruiters,
    setter: new HrInterviewStrategy(),
  },
};

// Determine interviewCategory (TECHNICAL_INTERVIEW or HR_INTERVIEW) and other required parameters
const interviewCategory = 'HR_INTERVIEW';
const param3 = 'value3';
const param4 = 'value4';
const slotsWithEmail = {}; // Replace with the appropriate value

// Call validateRecruiters based on interview type
const matchedSlots = getMatchingSlots(
  recruitersCategoryHandlers[interviewCategory].setter.validateRecruiters(
    recruitersCategoryHandlers[interviewCategory].getter(),
    slotsWithEmail,
    param3,
    param4
  ),
  slotsWithEmail
);
```